# In ArcPy, update rows if the column exists, loop through all layers

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Using ArcPy within ArcMap I want to loop through all layers in a geodatabase, if a column exists then I want to change the value in that column.

For instance, I have 3 feature classes layer1, layer2, layer3.

The code column exists in layer1 and layer3.

Currently the code column values are a mix of null, 'abc' and 'def', I want them all to be 'def'.

Any pointers?

Comment: Not to be fussy on semantics, but I do think word choice can make a difference in communicating one's issue.  In light of that, geodatabases do store layers and naming features classes `layer1`, `layer2`, etc... could get confusing when describing a problem if one arises.

Answer (score 2):

1. [ListFeatureClasses](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm), for each fc:
2. [ListFields](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm) to search for the field, if found:
3. [UpdateCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to modify the values